# How to combine two lists of lists into a pandas DataFrame in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dataframe

I have two lists. The one has  ids(of some sub_graphs) and the other the frequency of appearance of each subgraph(some values).Each list is a list of lists(with diferent sizes).I want to create a dataframe, each id of subgraph to be a columname. After that I woud like for each row of the ids list to check the relevant value in the values list and to save this value in relevant dataframe column.
In more detail I have these two lists:

```
*id_graph=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,4]]
value_graph=[[11,22,33,44],[11,1],[122,9,1],[1,14]]*
```

I want as an output a dataframe such as:

```
     1    2       3     4
0   11.0    22.0    33.0    44.0
1   11.0    1.0 NaN NaN
2   122.0   9.0 1.0 NaN
3   1.0 NaN NaN 14.0
```

Firstly I have created an empty df with columns names that I want
After that I use a loop just to define df different rows and two for loops and zip to save the values to dataframe

```
*import pandas as pd
a=[1,2,3,4]
a=list(a)
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=a)
id_graph=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,4]]
value_graph=[[11,22,33,44],[11,1],[122,9,1],[1,14]]
for row in range(0,len(id_graph)):
    for a, b in zip(id_graph, value_graph):
        for i,j in zip(a,b):
            df.loc[row,i]=j
            print("row:",row,"id:",i,"value:",j)*
```

So although I want as output a df such as:

```
     1    2       3     4
0   11.0    22.0    33.0    44.0
1   11.0    1.0      NaN    NaN
2   122.0   9.0      1.0    NaN
3   1.0      NaN     NaN    14.0
```

my output is:

```
     1  2   3   4
0   1.0 9.0 1.0 14.0
1   1.0 9.0 1.0 14.0
2   1.0 9.0 1.0 14.0
3   1.0 9.0 1.0 14.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach, but I can image there is something smoother. For example, I created the df assuming you know how many columns you will have.

```
import pandas as pd
a=[1,2,3,4]
a=list(a)
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=a)
id_graph=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,4]]
value_graph=[[11,22,33,44],[11,1],[122,9,1],[1,14]]
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=[1,2,3,4])
i=0
for id_, value in zip(id_graph, value_graph):

    for n, val in zip(id_,value):
        df.loc[i,n]=val
    i+=1
```

Comment: Yes in my problem I know how many columns I have. I appreciate your help.Thank you very much